# Return a number between 0 and 4

Tags: algorithm, numbers

How do I return a number between 0 and 4, depending the input number?

For example if I pass it number 23 it will return 3. The number set should look like

**0** 5 10 15 20 ..

**1** 6 11 16 21 ..

**2** 7 12 17 22 ..

**3** 8 13 18 23 ..

**4** 9 14 19 24

What's the math for this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the [*modulo*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operator) operation, typically `%` in many languages (and `mod` in many others).

```
10 % 5 = 0

17 % 3 = 2
```

Comment: +1. Ya beat me to it. Also called `return the remainder` in non-math speak. :-)

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operator

```
N % 5
```

Answer (score 2):

The above two answers are correct, the Modulo operator is very useful in calculating remainders.
For example the "pass 23 return 3" : 23 % 5 works as follows:
5 goes into 23 4 times ( (int) 23 / 5 = 4)
the modulo operater then gives you the remainder (23 - (5 * 4)), which happens to be the number you and your assignment are looking for, 3.